# if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=M$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)g(x)=LM$

Tags: limits

I am going through several of my book's proofs of statements related to "$x$ approaches $a$" and making sure they are also valid for statements of "$x$ approaches $\infty$".

For this post, I just wanted to make sure I am correctly proving the following statement:

> if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=M$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)g(x)=LM$

I will make use of the following lemma:

> If $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert M \rvert +1)}) $ and $\lvert g(x) - M\rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert L\rvert +1)}$, then $\lvert f(x)g(x)-LM \rvert \lt \epsilon$.

For notation purposes, consider these statements:

$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0\  \exists N \in \mathbb R \ \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt N \rightarrow \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$

$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=M \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0\  \exists P \in \mathbb R \ \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt P \rightarrow \lvert g(x) - M \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$

$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)g(x)=LM \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0\  \exists T \in \mathbb R \ \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ x \gt T \rightarrow \lvert f(x)g(x) - LM \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ]$

---

For further notational convenience, let $a:=1$, $b:=\frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert M \rvert +1)}$, and $c:=\frac{\epsilon}{2(\lvert L\rvert +1)}$

Therefore, consider the construction of the following $T$:

$$T=\max\Big(N_{\min (a,b)},P_c \Big)$$

For all $x$ larger than $T$, we will create the necessary conditions to ensure that $x \gt T \rightarrow \lvert f(x)g(x) - LM \rvert \lt \epsilon $.

All good?

Comment: Looks all good to me.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
|f(x)g(x) -LM| &= |(f(x) -L)(g(x)-M) - M(L-f(x)) - L(M - g(x))|\\
&\le |(f(x) -L)(g(x)-M)| + |M||L-f(x)| + |L||M - g(x)|
\end{align}
Let $K = \max \{|L|,|M|\}$.Suppose $N_f$ and $N_g$ are such that $x > N_f \implies |f(x) - L| < \min \left \{ \frac{\varepsilon}{3K}, |L| \right\}$  and $x > N_g \implies |g(x) - M| < \frac{\varepsilon}{3K}$

Then for $x > \max\{N_f,N_g \}$,
\begin{align}
|f(x)g(x) -LM| &\le |f(x) -L||g(x)-M| + |M||L-f(x)| + |L||M - g(x)|\\
&< |L|\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{3K} +  |M|\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{3K} + |L|\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{3K} \\
&\le \frac{\varepsilon}{3} +\frac{\varepsilon}{3} +\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align}